# How to test filename for occurrence of substring in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to test whether my filename ends in 'pos.txt' or 'neg.txt' in Python.

So for example, if my filename is 'samplepaths5000neg.txt'--how can I test for the ending? I've tried various Python regex expressions but I can't seem to get it correct. It's for a script that runs different actions depending on the filename.

Comment: What do you want a regex? Why not just `filename.endswith(('neg.txt', 'pos.txt'))`?

Comment: But if you really want help debugging your regex, you have to show us the regex you tried.

Comment: you can use the `str.endswith` to check. Link to tutorial here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm

Comment: You can use either a regex or endswith. In addition are there any constraints in the question?

Comment: Ok why am I getting downvoted for this question? I genuinely couldn't figure it out and I find that a question like mine is helpful.

Comment: @Glassjawed Your question is probably being downvoted because you did not show your approach. You are supposed to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Also, you got several comments asking for clarification and you ignored them. Please don't do that. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: Yea it turned out str.endswith works for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for end of string is the $ symbol.
So if you did want to use a regex expression for this example it would be:

```
(?:pos|neg)\.txt$
```

The (?: allows the creation of a group that isn't reported. Omitting the question mark colon would cause the group to be reported which you could use to find out if the file ended in positive or negative.

```
import re
file_name = "samplepaths5000neg.txt"
correct_ending = re.match(r'(?:pos|neg)\.txt$',file_name) != None
```

or if you want to capture the ending

```
ending_result = re.match(r'(pos|neg)\.txt$',file_name)
ending = ending_result.group(1) if ending_result!=None else ''
```

Shown matched against different filenames :

https://regex101.com/r/9TiFMr/1